# VisualStudio 2015 Universal app .NET parse json

Tags: json, win-universal-app

how to in VisualStudio 2015 (Net framewortk 4.5.2) downbload and parse JSON?

URL with JSON is: http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400

It is not necessary to parse the building. Just values sunrise and sunset

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two Nuget packages which make this very easy. HttpClient (package name Microsoft.Net.Http) will help you do the GET request. Json.Net (package name Newtonsoft.Json) make it very easy to deserialize JSON. It will allow you to do something like this:

```
using (HttpClient hClient = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await hClient.GetAsync(URL);
    string strContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourTypeHere>(strContent);
}
```